# Start NSInputStream at certain location

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsinputstream

I have an input stream and I want to start reading bytes at a certain location. Is there any way I can do that? Say I want to read `1024` bytes at location `n`, `n` being the `nth` byte in the file. How do I achieve this? I've looked at the documentation and there doesn't appear to be way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the below api for reading :-

```
+ (id)inputStreamWithFileAtPath:(NSString *)path

- (NSInteger)read:(uint8_t *)buffer maxLength:(NSUInteger)len;
```

Comment: Doesn't `read:maxlength:` read from the beginning of the file into the buffer?